# ncurses on adb shell android

Tags: android, c, shell, terminal, ncurses

I'm trying to create a minimalistic command line gui with ncurses on Android. I cross compiled ncurses for ARM64 etc and everything seems to run. However; when starting my test 'hello world' ncurses program in adb shell, I get the following error:

```
Error opening terminal: xterm-256color.
```

when i try to set TERM to xterm or something i get:

```
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

Is there any particular way I need to compile ncurses and/or configure Android to allow a CLI gui like this to run?

Comment: Check your environment variables: **TERM=xterm**, **TERMINFO=/path/to/terminfo**.

Comment: I set my term to xterm, still a similar error msg appears. No terminfo on Android I guess?

Comment: There is a folder called **terminfo** in ncurses package. Or you'll have to generate that thing, don't know don't remember. If you have a linux OS, this folder usually located at `/usr/share/terminfo`. The hierarchy should looks like this: `terminfo --> a  d  e  l  n  p  r  s  t  v  x` and inside the x folder, there are bunch of files named that starts with `xterm` e.g. `xterm`, `xterm-16color`, `xterm+256color`, `xterm-color`, etc

Comment: nope, terminfo does not exist on the Android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick was configuring ncurses like so:

```
./configure --without-database --with-fallbacks=xterm-256color,vt100 --without-xterm-new --disable-home-terminfo --with-termlib --enable-termcap --disable-database --host=arm-linux-gnue
```

This allowed the fallbacks to be used internally without relying on a library

Answer (score 1):

You need a terminal database to run curses applications.  Apparently none is installed (though it's possible that there is a terminal database whose location doesn't correspond to the compiled-in defaults for [`TERMINFO`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) or [`TERMINFO_DIRS`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS)).

With ncurses, you can configure and compile-in fallback entries (discussed in the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/cdacc540acd83a862a104a9b6ef72d37fb4e7a1d/INSTALL#L2193) source-file) which are used if the terminal description is not found in the terminal database:

> In order to support operation of ncurses programs before the terminfo
> tree is accessible (that is, in single-user mode or at OS installation
> time) the ncurses library can be compiled to include an array of
> pre-fetched fallback entries.
>
> NOTE: This must be done on a machine which has ncurses' infocmp and
> terminfo database installed (as well as ncurses' tic and infocmp
> programs).  That is because the fallback sources are generated and
> compiled into the library before the build-tree's copy of infocmp is
> available.
>
> These entries are checked by setupterm() only when the conventional
> fetches from the terminfo tree and the termcap fallback (if configured)
> have been tried and failed.  Thus, the presence of a fallback will not
> shadow modifications to the on-disk entry for the same type, when that
> entry is accessible.

Comment: So it can still use these fallback entries if they are not on the system? It will build these fall back entries into itself during compile time?

Comment: The entries have to be available on the machine where the fallback-entries are compiled.